# Php json_encode converts utf8 string to characters codes

Tags: php

I have a Persian text `"سرما"`

And then when I convert it to JSON using `json_encode()`, I get a series of escaped character codes such as `\u0633` which seems to be expected and of a rational process. But my confusion lies where I don't know how to convert them back into readable string of characters. How should I do that in PHP?

Should I use anything of mb_* family? I also have checked `json_encode()` parameters and have found nothing appropriate for me.

**UPDATE**
what I get saved in my DB is:
["u0633u0631u0645u0627"]

Which shows the characters are not escaped properly. While if I change it to
`["\u0633\u0631\u0645\u0627"]` it becomes easily readable by `json_decode()`

Comment: Doesn't `json_decode` do what you want?

Comment: No it doesn't, it just give them back as they are. I mean with \u* notation...

Comment: It works for me. I get back the original string with Persian characters.

Comment: See demo: http://ideone.com/uYwBG4

Comment: Based on your demo, I have updated the question.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with how you're saving to the DB. Why are you converting to JSON when you store in the DB, it should be able to store UTF-8 characters directly without conversion.

Comment: Solved.  Based on the answer give by @Sammitch. The issue was with the way data was saved in the DB. Thank you

Comment: It does indeed seem like you're not escaping properly when you save to the DB. You should use a prepared statement rather than substituting variables, then you don't have to worry about escaping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They should be converted back on the other end when it's decoded. This is the safest option as it might not be possible to guaranteed that the transmission or storage will not corrupt a multi-byte encoding.

If you're certain that everything is safe for UTF8 end-to-end you can do:

```
$res = json_encode($foo, \JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: You still need to fix your escaping problem when storing in the DB. If it's not escaping backslashes, it's not escaping other special characters, so you're open to SQL injection.

Comment: Indeed I'm so aware of SQL-Injection. My case is a special one. I am not even used to store data in DB in an aggregated fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try encoding the unicode characters, and then json_encoding it, then on the other side (receiving JSON) decode the json, then decode the unicode.

Example:

```
//Encode
json_encode(utf8_encode($string));

//Decode
utf8_decode(json_decode($string));
```

Answer (score 0):

its simple just use JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES atribute
your problem is't utf8  you need force JSON to don't escape Slashes

example

```
$bar = "سرما";
$res = json_encode($bar, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );
// $res equal to ["\u0633\u0631\u0645\u0627"]
```

if you check the result in your MYSQL Database
it happen when you did't Use addslashes() 
example

```
$bar = "سرما";
$res = json_encode($bar, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );
$res = addslashes($res);
// $res equal to ["\\u0633\\u0631\\u0645\\u0627"] now it's ready to use in MYSQL
```